# What is an alternative for this solution made with css grid?

Tags: html, css, css-grid

I aligned these boxes with css grid as shown below and in the JSfiddle.

The container basically wraps the content of my website, in this case the grid. It works exactly like I want it to work. However, I just noticed that the grid is not supported in iOS 10.2.

Could you provide an alternative that has a better compatibility? I of course tried it myself but I was only successful with grid.

```css
html {
  font-size: 62.5%;
}

.container {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 1100px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0 20px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  background-color: lightblue;
}

.box {
  width: 100%;
  display: grid;
  grid-auto-rows: 35rem;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, minmax(27rem, 1fr));
  grid-gap: 4em;
}

.boxWrapper {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.innerBox {
  height: 35rem;
  width: 27rem;
  padding: 2rem;
  background-color: grey;
  border-radius: 2rem;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="box">
    <div class="boxWrapper">
      <div class="innerBox">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="boxWrapper">
      <div class="innerBox">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="boxWrapper">
      <div class="innerBox">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="boxWrapper">
      <div class="innerBox">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="boxWrapper">
      <div class="innerBox">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="boxWrapper">
      <div class="innerBox">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/213ksqhd/)

Answer (score -2):

You could easily do this whit flexbox.
In this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/213ksqhd/65/) I've only set the element `box` to flex and set its childrens to occupy the half of the entire space less the space I want to leave between each others.